# How can I output text until it is ascii in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, while-loop, char, ascii

How can I output text until it is ascii in SQL?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20)
SET @input = 'text'

DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 1

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(32)
SET @output = ''

WHILE CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1))) LIKE '[ -~]'
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)))
    SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT @output
```

But in the end I am getting an empty string. Why? What am I missing here?

I am expecting the value of the `@output` to be `'text'` in the end of the script.

**UPDATE**

If I update the script to the

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20)
SET @input = 'text'

DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 1

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(32)
SET @output = ''

WHILE CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1))) LIKE '[a-b]'
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)))
    SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT @output
```

It will work as expected. But here I just shrinked the set from all printable ascii characters to only small letters. Why does the shrinked set `[a-b]` include the `text` characters and the extended set `[ -~]` does not?

Comment: `NOT LIKE`? Or what is that `LIKE` predicate supposed to do? But you could do this as a one liner `SELECT ISNULL(SUBSTRING(@input, 1, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[ -~]%', @input), 0)), @input)`

Comment: @Charlieface, but what is wrong in my implementation? The `LIKE` checks that a `char` is ASCII.

Comment: No idea as I don't know what you are trying to do, what does "Until it is ASCII mean", the query as it stands is trying to find a space, a dash or tilde, all of which are ASCII characters

Comment: @Charlieface, the query iterates over the input characters one by one and appends the characters to the output until it meets a first non ascii character.

Comment: So as I thought: you are trying to output until the first *non-ASCII* character (and I don't know what that means), but that is not what this query does, it returns all characters which match space, dash, tilde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is not a valid range delimiter so `LIKE [ -~]` will not work. That becomes a test for those three characters only.

You could check the ASCII code directly, rather than using `LIKE`:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(20)
SET @input = 'text'

DECLARE @index INT
SET @index = 1

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(32)
SET @output = ''

WHILE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)) BETWEEN 32 AND 126
BEGIN
    SET @output = @output + CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@input, @index, 1)))
    SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT @output
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6bcc8eef7157095144e8bf4b9c0daa0)

Side note: It's possible to get [unexpected results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34730/why-are-non-digits-like-0-9) with `LIKE` ranges because the comparison is collation-aware.

---

<sub>Answer copied from the [duplicate question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/287759) on Database Administrators</sub>